# Замена контактной информации

Tags: django

Как модели использовать для замены контактов через админ панель. С формами разобрался, а вот это никак не могу понять, возможно это вообще реализовывается как то иначе, подскажите как мне это риализавать? Буду рад любой информации!
Делаю так:

```
class Contacts (models.Model):
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    working = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит «какие модели»? Просто берите да создавайте нужную вам модель с нужными вам полями. Непонятно в чём проблема у вас

Comment: @andreymal Везде описано что модель привязывается к форме ввода, а тут просто текст с контактной информацией

Comment: Вы что-то странное пишете, в [официальном учебнике Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/) с самого начала учат, как выводить данные из объектов моделей, без всяких форм